# Limit number of javascript automated generated checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, checkbox

kinda worried with following code that should automatically generate checkbox content AND limit up to 3 the number of checked boxes.

Separately both codes work fine, the issue occurs when they are combined:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zhkqy8bm/3/)

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(e) {
  if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 3) {
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
  }
})

var skills = ["centres", "tirs", "dribbles", "passes", "vitesse"]
var skillContainer = $("#skillsContainer");
skills.forEach(skill => skillContainer.append('<li> <input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"' + skill + '\" value=\"' + skill + '\"> <label for=\"' + skill + '\"> ' + skill + ' </label> </li>'));

$("#skillsContainer").append(checkboxElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="competencies" action="algo.php" method="POST">

  <div class="container">
    <ul class="ks-cboxtags" id="skillsContainer">
      <input class="button" type="submit" value="Valider">
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. There is no checkboxElement in your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean this?

You need to delegate when you create dynamic elements

OR add the event handler after the generation

```js
$('#skillsContainer').on("change", 'input[type=checkbox]', function(e) {
  if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 3) {
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
  }
})

var skills = ["centres", "tirs", "dribbles", "passes", "vitesse"]
$("#skillsContainer").html(skills.map(skill => '<li> <input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"' + skill + '\" value=\"' + skill + '\"> <label for=\"' + skill + '\"> ' + skill + ' </label> </li>').join(""));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="competencies" action="algo.php" method="POST">

  <div class="container">
    <ul class="ks-cboxtags" id="skillsContainer">
      <input class="button" type="submit" value="Valider">
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Just add a little note to this perfectly working answer. The OP code won't work because when it runs line by line there is no element such as input with type checkbox so `$('input[type=checkbox]')` won't find anything and the `change` event won't work either. So changing the order of your code also may solve your problem (moving the `change` event to the bottom).

Comment: @SMAKSS Yeah, should have elaborated. I have updated my answer

Comment: @mplungjan and SMAKSS, it works like a charm ! thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Pure javascript to check checked checkbox length

```
var eLength = element.length;
var i = 0;
var checkedCheck;
checkbox.forEach(checkBox => {
     checkBox.addEventListener('click',function(){
          if(this.checked){
              i++;
              if(i > 3){
                  checkBox.disabled = true;
                  alert('Limit reached');
              }
        }
    });
});
```